# Fullcalender display previous and next month entry how to hide this

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar, yii-extensions

when i dynamically load event in fullcalender at this time preview month entry also be display

Example

if user on July 2014 then last few date of June 2014 is disable but event of that date will be display is there any option to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulties understanding your question....  Do you only want the user to see the events of the current (this) month?  If so, try this:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if(event.start.getMonth() !== view.start.getMonth()) { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

It's simply not rendering them.